# An algorithem for finding the number of primes of the form 4k+3 under some n

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, number-theory, primes

I was given the task to make an algorithem that can compute the number of prime's of the form 4k+3 under some n, it should be able to compute how many number's of this type are there under 10^8 (100 million) in less than 10 minutes, any ideas?

Iv'e tried using variation's on the Sieve of Eratosthenes and lagranages method but the first was too slow and i didnt manage to have the second count only primes of the form 4k+3.

Comment: (`< 10 minutes, any ideas?` 1st: off topic, 2nd: old - an Apple M1 can probably brute force it. (3rd: without a capital L, it looks like you misspelled lasagne.))

Comment: [Atkin's sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) computes them in under a second in my computer. I tried [this implementation](http://cr.yp.to/primegen.html), which gives you all the primes. You just need to remove the primes of the form $4k+1$ and $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple algorithm in Python that count the primes of the form $4k+3$ that are less than a positive integer $n$. It uses the standard sieve of Eratosthenes.

```python
import math

def number_of_primes_4kp3(n):
    is_prime = [True] * n

    for p in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):
        if is_prime[p]:
            for j in range(p * p, n, p):
                is_prime[j] = False

    count = 0
    for i in range(3, n, 4):
        if is_prime[i]:
            count += is_prime[i]

    return count

print("n    ", "number of primes 4k+3")
for i in range(1, 9):
    count = number_of_primes_4kp3(10 ** i)
    print("10**" + str(i), count)
```

It takes about 20 seconds for the Python program above on an old Mac computer of mine to compute `number_of_primes_4kp3(10 ** 8)`, returning `2880950`.

When I use Java instead and only compute `is_prime` for odd numbers (which doubles the performance roughly), it takes less than half a second.